# Sending Ionic push notifications, neo4j

Tags: ionic-framework, neo4j, push-notification, nestjs

I am developing an Ionic application, which has a NestJS backend. I want to send push notifications to the user, when he receives a friend request, or something similar, but my main problem is I am not using firebase (which seems to handle them well), I am using Neo4j. Is there a simple way I could handle push notifications in my case?

Also, I am not an expert in push notifications, so I was thinking, is there a way to send a push notification from my NestJS backend, when a certain endpoint/method is executed?

Answer (score 1):

You can send push notification using [OneSignal](http://onesignal.com/) which support Nest you can check this plugin [onesignal-api-client-nest](https://www.npmjs.com/package/onesignal-api-client-nest)

and for ionic you can check the official plugin from [here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/onesignal)